# Зачем нужен шаблон angular в проекте asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, angular

Какая разница между тем, что бы создать отдельное клиентское приложение на angular(которое лежит отдельно от бека) и шаблоном angular которое создается вместе с asp.net core приложением?

> С начала мне показалось, что он нужен для серверного рендеринга, но
>   там нет такого из коробки и нужно тоже пошаманить, что бы он заработал
>   . В итоге мне кажется что смысла нет тащить за собой в angular еще и
>   asp.net core приложение. Лучше что бы были 2 разных проекта в разных
>   папках и они знали о друг друге, только через api и ничего большего.

Comment: Если есть такой шаблон - значит кому то он понадобился. Я тоже пишу фронт отдельно, но я думаю, что лучше иметь выбор как писать (все в одном решении или отдельно), чем не иметь.

Comment: @tym32167 Значит более частая практика связки angular и asp.net именно front отдельно, а back отдельно? Просто решил посмотреть примеры работы на github и там большинство работают именно через шаблон. Именно это меня и заставило задаться вопросом о правильной связке.

Comment: Не знаю частая или не частая практика, я только предпочитаю отделять мух от котлет. Бекенд я пишу на C# и делаю это удобными мне инструместами. Фронт я пишу на Typescript в VSCode. Более того, жесткой связи между беком и фротном нет, потому нет причин для меня держать их вместе. Но это мой случай, а может кто то делает иначе - вот для них и есть тот шаблон.

Comment: @tym32167 Спасибо за ваш ответ, мне тоже изначально импонирует стиль разделения, что бы никто никому не мешал, но репозитории на github немного пошатнули мое мнение. Еще раз спасибо)